# Spring - two different POST methods with the same URL but different produced content type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have the following controller:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class OwnerViewController implements ApiOwnerViewController {

    private static final String TEXT_CSV = "text/csv";

    private final PrivateOwnerFacade privateOwnerFacade;

    @PostMapping("/boat/v1/private-owners/search")
    public OwnerViewResponse searchOwners(@Valid @RequestBody SearchOwnersRequest request,
                                          Pageable pageable) {
        return privateOwnerFacade.findOwners(request, pageable);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/boat/v1/private-owners/search", produces = TEXT_CSV)
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> exportToCsv(@Valid @RequestBody SearchOwnersRequest request, Pageable pageable)
            throws IOException {
```

So I have two methods mapped to the same url and that both accept POST request BUT produce different content type - the first one produces `application/json` while the second produces `text/csv`.

Then, when I'm trying to make a request and set header
`Accept: text/csv` I get 406 from the server.

I wonder if it is really possible to do such things with spring? Or is the only way to change second method so that it accepts `GET` requests?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you add `produces = APPLICTION_JSON` to the first method?

Comment: @JBNizet please add your answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class SearchController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/search", produces = {APPLICATION_JSON})
    public SearchResponse search(@Valid @RequestBody SearchRequest request,
                                          Pageable pageable) {
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/search", produces = {TEXT_CSV})
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> export(@Valid @RequestBody SearchRequest request, Pageable pageable) throws IOException {

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that request with text/csv matches both endpoints.
you can use negative values on the annotation, so the first one will match only non-text/csv requests:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/boat/v1/private-owners/search", produces = "!text/csv")
public OwnerViewResponse searchOwners(@Valid @RequestBody SearchOwnersRequest 
                                      request,
                                      Pageable pageable) {
    return privateOwnerFacade.findOwners(request, pageable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use one Method with a @PostMapping, return a response entity and dynamically set the Content-Type-Response-Header.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/api-endpoint")
    public ResponseEntity<String> method(@RequestParam("produces") String produces) {

        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

        if (produces.equals("text/csv")) {
            responseHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("text", "csv"));
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("foo;bar", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            responseHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "json"));
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"foo\": \"bar\"}", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. 1st in the question user tries to perform POST request, not GET. 2nd the question was - "is it possible to do POST mapping to the same path with different content types." - and it's possible as shown in the accepted answer. Let's give comprehensive and correct answers and not mislead people.

Comment: @Vusal One can simply change \@GetMapping to \@PostMapping and add the desired RequestParams into the Method-signature. I wanted to keep it as simple to show how to have the same endpoint with different content-types. But yes I agree, the accepted answer is a neater solution than my approach.