# Unable to have a method with application/json or multipart/form-data in SPRING java

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I'm trying to create a method that either receives a JSON or a .csv file in order to populate a database. It goes like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,
consumes = {"multipart/form-data","application/json"})
public ResponseEntity<PeopleResponse> create(
        @RequestBody People PeopleDTO,
        @RequestParam(name = "csvFile", required = false) MultipartFile csvFile,
        HttpServletRequest request)
```

When I try it with Postman with a json sending:

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:9001/people' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJtcmVnYWxhZG8iLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6eyJsb2dpbiI6IjEiLCJnb2RNb2RlIjoiMSIsInJlZ2lzdGVyIjoiMSJ9LCJzYWx0IjoxNTg5NTg2ODgwMzI1LCJzb3VyY2UiOiJsb2NhbGhvc3QifQ.DrdUC7JN-Db0-_6qNGn9i5n3YzVopGNisecLy08SvMCudmveZnwATRwMftf2VKBZqhUKdQIrJGsNXudU1uwTgA' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "Homer",
    "age": 25

}'
```

It works, but when I try it sending a csv file with Postman, it fails:

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:9001/people' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJtcmVnYWxhZG8iLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6eyJsb2dpbiI6IjEiLCJnb2RNb2RlIjoiMSIsInJlZ2lzdGVyIjoiMSJ9LCJzYWx0IjoxNTg5NTg2ODgwMzI1LCJzb3VyY2UiOiJsb2NhbGhvc3QifQ.DrdUC7JN-Db0-_6qNGn9i5n3YzVopGNisecLy08SvMCudmveZnwATRwMftf2VKBZqhUKdQIrJGsNXudU1uwTgA' \
--form 'csvFile=@/home/myself/Downloads/people.csv' \
```

It gives me the following error:

```
2020-10-05 15:09:20.602 WARN  13086 - [nio-9001-exec-3] s.w.s.h.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver | Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------276557520366487467828532;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to have either application/json or multipart/form-data in one method or if the only way is to make two separates methods (Though it ruins a little the naming, because second method would be like "POST people/by-file"

Comment: Are you sure that the --form is appropriate for a CSV file ? wouldn't you rather use a binary ? Are using the postman GUI to do this request ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using postman GUI and the method works if I remove @RequestBody People PeopleDTO. That's why I'm asking if it's possible to have both in one method.

Comment: In your second request you're not specifying the Content-Type as header, and if I remember correctly @RequestBody, is required by default .
This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113230/spring-two-different-post-methods-with-the-same-url-but-different-produced-con has answers that provide what you want (phip1611 answer).
But I don't think that having two differents methods is such a bad thing, it might even easier to read

Comment: Yes, sorry, the examples are taken as cURL from Postman, but they have "multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>" as content type when trying to send csv file and "application/json" when sending just a body. From what I'm seeing, you can't have a RequestBody and also send a File, I just wanted to know if there was a way. I guess I can send the json as form-data instead of body, but just a thought

Comment: We'll have to wait on someone more's experienced answer, sorry I can't help you much, I'd also like to know the answer